# Spring-boot application does not close child management context on exception in main context bean initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I use Spring-Boot 1.5 framework for my web application. Also I use actuators on different port (property management.port=8081). Cause of different management port Spring creates child context for management endpoints.

I faced following issue. When bean from main context throws exception on start (bean implements Lifecycle.start()) then main context is closed but child context proceeds to work. This prevents my application from exit that is desirable for application in such case. I also have checked this behavior on Spring-Boot 2.

Should I configure my application in some special way or it is normal behavior and I should implement some try-catch-exit logic by myself?

Comment: Hi Sergey, similar problem here ... did you find a solution to your problem ?